# Is there any preferred way to change versions with files in git?

Tags: git, version-control

I have to work with a *5GB* repo. Most of the time I don't have to make changes to the individual files, but I run a script that changes, adds, and removes many files.

Now, there can be some breaking changes that are caused by these external scripts.

Is there a way in `Git` to revert back to the state before running the script if the script doesn't work as expected?

I tried `git tag` and `git branch` but somehow when I checkout the `tag` or switch back to `master` branch, the files that are changed get their original state but the files that are added also remain there instead of  going away.

What am I doing wrong?

How can I manage this kind of scenario when a script changes so many files and the result does not work?  Can I easily revert back to the state before running the script?

---

Here is what I'm doing. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

```
mkdir git-learning
touch basic-file1 basic-file2 basic-file3
git init
git add .
git commit -m "At the start: first version"
```

After this `git status` shows working directory is clean.

```
touch new-file1 new-file2 new-file3
git add .
git commit -m "second version: possibly wrong changes"
git reset --hard
git clean -f
```

Now `git status` shows nothing to commit, working directory is clean.

But still it shows, all the files including `new-file1`, `new-file2` and `new-file3` when I run `ls` command. But I need some command that will show just `basic-file1`, `basic-file2`, `basic-file3` and blow away all other new files.

How can I do that?

Comment: Since we don't know your scripts we would have to speculate... So the answer is: yes there is some command to fix your state. no, no one knows what it is.

Comment: They are diffrent from time to time. No single script is run again if it works.
Is git suited for this kind of scenario or should I use good old copy-paste-backup system ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `git reset` and `git clean` commands to reset & clean your working tree when you want to revert all of your changes.  The following commands will brute-force clean & reset your working tree to an entirely clean state:

```
git reset --hard <rev>
git clean -f
```

Be careful with `git clean -f` as it will remove all files that are not tracked by git.  Make sure that this is what you actually want to do and make the appropriate backups before proceeding.

Comment: Be careful with `git clean`. That removes files not under version control.

Comment: That's correct, but I believe that this is exactly what the OP wants.  "...but the files that are added also remains there instead of just going away"   I will add a warning to my answer.

Comment: Yes. Basically my need is to revert back to `exact snapshot` of the folder structure at particular time (say before running some script) with exact folder structure at that time ... not a file more or less.

Comment: So then my answer should work for you.  If it does, please accept it as the correct answer :-)

Comment: I'm trying that only. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. But here is what I have exactly done.

`mkdir git-learning`
`touch basic-file1 basic-file2 basic-file3`

`git init` and `git add .` and `git commit -m "At the start : first version"`

`git status` : shows working directory is clean. 

--
`touch new-file1 new-file2 new-file3`

`git add .`
`git commit -m "second version : possibly wrong changes"`

`git reset --hard` and then `git clean -f `
`git status` : shows nothing to commit, working directoy is clean.

but still it shows, alll files including new-file1, 2 and 3 when I run `ls` command.

Comment: Ah, then you should simply supply the hash id of the commit you want to revert to after the `git reset` command.  For example: `git reset --hard <rev>` and then do the `git clean -f` afterwards

Comment: @mkrufky On a side-note is it possible to do the same thing on different branch also ... so when I checkout master it shows just `basic-file 1,2 &3` and  when I checkout `new-branch` and create `new-file1,2and3` and then it will show `basic-file1,2,3` and `new-file1,2,3`. And then when I checkout master again it shows just basic-files1,2and3 ?

Comment: you can `git reset --hard` on any branch to any rev.  I'm not sure if that answers your question... I'm a bit confused as per what you're asking.